# Group as owner of a record

Tags: security, sharing, owner

I want a core group of people to have access to create/edit a bunch of records. This group would be a Management Team, anyone in that team can create/edit these records. However I want team members who report to the management team to have the ability to add child/related records and have read access to the top level records. I appreciate that master detail is not the way to go with this since security would be controlled at the top level which I don't want.

Since you can not assign a group as the record owner the only thing I can think of is to use a queue but I'm not sure if it's best practice to leave a queue as the owner of a bunch of records? Secondly the creator can manually share the record with a group but that is a manual process.

What would be the usual approach for something like this? I need a core team to own all the records, additional users need access to read them and create related records. The core team should still end up with full access to the related records as well automatically.

Thanks

Comment: Assign all of the record to one of the user of the group, and create a criteria based sharing rules to give read/write access to group members.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest following solution:

1) Assign all records to one of the user from the group(instead of assigning it to queue).

2) Create a criteria based sharing rule to give Read/Write access to the group.

3) The team which reports to Management team should be on different profile where you can give access to create child object record but not parent.